# "javax.servlet.ServletException: non-HTTP request or response" in JBoss

Tags: java, exception, jboss

My jboss is throwing undescriptive error while trying to run my application (spring mvc). It deploys ok, and this exception doesn't tell me anything useful so I don't really know what to do. I can't debug , can't do anything really :

```
    13:00:01,262 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221053)] Started in 2m:13s:790ms

**Started successfully**
```

While running the application from the browser this happens :

```
13:00:09,456 ERROR [[appServlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: non-HTTP request or response
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:818)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This gets thrown in `HttpServlet.service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse)` when the parameters can't be cast to `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` respectively.

That means one of two things:

- the parameters are of the wrong type (unlikely) or
- some filter is using the wrong copy of those types, loaded with a wrong classloader (for example if you deliver your own copy of `servlet-api-x.x.jar` with your webapp).

Comment: The parameters can be the wrong type if you happen to be using `ServletRequestWrapper` instead of `HttpServletRequestWrapper`

Comment: Thanks, @kuporific, changing to a HttpServletRequestWrapper fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try removing servlet-api jar from your WAR file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven, you can just set the scope of the `servlet-api`  to `provided`.