# HTTP Status Code 201 with multipart/mixed response

Tags: rest, jboss, resteasy

I'm trying to create a REST service defined as:

```
@POST
@Path("/path")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces("multipart/mixed")
public MultipartOutput create(MyObject o) {}
```

First part of the output will be an XML, second part a text file. In the XML I have the status code that I need, but how can I use it to create the HTTP status code? Currently I receive 200, I need 201.

(For other services, without MultipartOutput, the response is created using ResponseBuilder).

Comment: I've voted eiden's answer because solves exactly my initial requirements. But I've used finally another solution: I've modified the service to return Response instead of MultipartOutput and create the response using `Response.status(201).entity(mop).build();` where mop is the MultipartOutput object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You can use the `@Context` to access the `HttpServletResponse`.</strike>

Try changing your method signature and call `setStatus`:

```
public MultipartOutput create(MyObject o, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
    MultipartOutput mpo = ...
    response.setStatus(201);

    return mpo;
}
```

**EDIT :**

Try using `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpResponse` instead together with a `PostProcessInterceptor`:

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher;
import org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponse;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockDispatcherFactory;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockHttpRequest;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockHttpResponse;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartOutput;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpResponse;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.interception.PostProcessInterceptor;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class MultipartTest {
    @XmlRootElement(name = "MyObject")
    static class MyObject {}

    @Path("/")
    public static class Service {
        @Context HttpResponse response;

        @GET
        @Path("/mpo")
        public MultipartOutput create() {
            response.setStatus(201);

            final MultipartOutput mpo = new MultipartOutput();
            mpo.addPart(new MyObject(), MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);

            return mpo;
        }
    }

    public static class Interceptor implements PostProcessInterceptor {
        @Context HttpResponse response;

        @Override
        public void postProcess(ServerResponse serverResponse) {
            serverResponse.setStatus(response.getStatus());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Dispatcher dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
        dispatcher.getRegistry().addSingletonResource(new Service());
        dispatcher.getProviderFactory().getServerPostProcessInterceptorRegistry().register(new Interceptor());

        MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.get("/mpo");
        MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();

        dispatcher.invoke(request, response);

        Assert.assertEquals(201, response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using JBOSS 1.5. If I use `@Context HttpServletResponse`, I receive `javax.servlet.ServletException: non-HTTP request or response` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117121/javax-servlet-servletexception-non-http-request-or-response-in-jboss)