# Class.ForName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") throwing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, web-applications

I am getting a ClassNotFoundException when I attempt to define a driver for a SQLServer database in java code.

## [image: Image of code and error message.]

Can anyone clarify why this might be, I've seen similar questions but none of their answers seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse already shows the possible fixes, it's *possible* that `Class.forName` throws an exception (if the class cannot be located) hence you need to throw or catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a compilation error.

When you call `Class.forName()` the method may throw the checked exception `ClassNotFoundException`.  Since it is a checked exception your code must either handle it in the current method, or declare it in the method's `throws` clause.

I suggest that you read the Java tutorial's lesson on [exceptions and exception handling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/), or the Q&A that I have marked this as a dup of.

Note that if this exception actually occurs when your application is run, it means that the `Class.forName` was unable to load the JDBC driver class that you named.  This typically means that the JAR containing the driver class is not on the runtime classpath.  Unless your application can proceed without talking to the database at all(!), this is an exception that it won't be able to recover from.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on this. By the way, could this explain why eventually I get a ServletException error saying "non http request or response" when I attempt to use the servlet? (I'm clutching at straws with this one, I know)

Comment: I doubt it.  See this Q&A - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117121/javax-servlet-servletexception-non-http-request-or-response-in-jboss.  If you get stuck, you could ask a new Question: include the full stacktrace and relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

So basically the screenshot says that you have to catch `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
try {
   Class.forName("...");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   // log exception here
}
```

or re-throw it in your method signature

```
void doSmth() throws ClassNotFoundexception {
    ...
    Class.forName("...");
    ...
}
```